# Split en Haskell, no entiendo a que se refiere con "una sola pasada"

Tags: haskell, split

Consideremos la siguiente función

```
split:: (Ord a)=> a->[a]->([a],[a])
split x l = ( [y |y <- l, y <=x] , [y|y <- l, y > x])
```

Defina una versión de esta función que trabaje en exactamente una sola pasada a la lista “l“.

Comment: En la definición que te muestran tienes dos _compresiones_ de listas, cada una recorre la lista `l`, o sea, se recorre dos veces de principio a fin. Tienes que idear un modo de que la lista sólo sea recorrida una vez de principio a fin. Añade a la pregunta el código que hayas intentado y miraremos cómo poder ayudarte.

Comment: Lo intente con un if, pero no obtuve resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Habría varias formas. Una podría ser mediante dobleces:

```hs
split :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
split x xs = foldl aux ([],[]) xs
  where aux (ys,zs) w | w <= x = (w:ys, zs)
                      | otherwise = (ys, w:zs)
```

Más clara queda definida por recursividad:

```hs
split :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
split _ [] = ([],[])
split x (y:ys) | y <= x = (y:zs, ws)
               | otherwise = (zs, y:ws)
  where zs, ws = split x ys
```

Incluso una versión compacta con aplicativos, más matemática:

```hs
split :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
split x = (,) <$> filter (<= x) <*> filter (> x)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora sí entiendo 